# Assignment in loop then breaking

Tags: javascript

I am coming from a C/Python background and the following JavaScript code is puzzling me.
Why is the value of `c` at the end of the program not `6`? Because we are assigning and breaking afterwards. (I have run this on JSFiddle)

```js
function funct() {
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(6);
  bytes[0] = 228;
  bytes[1] = 191;
  bytes[2] = 157;
  bytes[3] = 233;
  bytes[4] = 153;
  bytes[5] = 186;
  bytes[6] = 255;
  bytes[7] = 17;
  bytes[8] = 23;
  bytes[9] = 223;
  var c = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    if (bytes[i] == 255) {
      c = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(i);
  console.log(c);
}

funct();
```

Output:

```
6
0
```

Comment: The loop never reaches the `break`. It ends after `i = 5` because that's the length of `bytes`

Comment: why are you defining this size of your array? why not just write: `var bytes = [228, 191, 157, 233, 153, 186, 255]`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Indeed the problem was with the declaration of the initial array size. I guess there is no bounds checking when assigning a value in an array.

Comment: With typed arrays, there is indeed bounds checking. If the index is out of bounds, then (unlike with C) the assignment becomes a no-op. Javascript doesn't assign the value to some memory location past the end of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is of size 6, but index 6 is the 7th entry. You need to allocate more space for your array:

```js
function funct() {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(10);
    bytes[0] = 228;
    bytes[1] = 191;
    bytes[2] = 157;
    bytes[3] = 233;
    bytes[4] = 153;
    bytes[5] = 186;
    bytes[6] = 255;
    bytes[7] = 17;
    bytes[8] = 23;
    bytes[9] = 223;
    var c = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if (bytes[i] == 255) {
            c = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(i);
    console.log(c);
}
    
funct();
```

Answer (score 4):

`bytes` has 6 elements it breaks at 5 never reach the if statement; on 
`bytes = new Uint8Array(6);` you should declare it like `bytes = new Uint8Array(10)`

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `var bytes = new Uint8Array(6)` which means it can hold only 6 elements and rest are ignored from `bytes[6]... bytes[9]`. Which means that `if`condition is never true and loop exist naturally without break.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 1):

you are asking for trouble by defining the size of your array:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(6);
```

instead do this;

```
var bytes = [];
bytes.push(228);
bytes.push(191);
bytes.push(157);
```

etc...

or:

```
var bytes = [228, 191, 157];
```

Comment: An array is not the same thing as a typed array. For the posted code, the differences are irrelevant, so an array as you suggest would do nicely. However, perhaps this code is the beginning of some larger code that requires a typed array.

Comment: in theory, you are probably correct. although in reality, unless you are worried about running out of CPU memory, there's probably no good reason to define the size of your array.